# What Does Expression: cannot dereference end list iterator mean?

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error message on my code, its saying its on line 149, but there's nothing on line 149 and so I'm having trouble understanding what is wrong. Does anyone know?

Context - this is a simple balancing symbols checker program exercise

This is the error message *after* i type in the name of the file.

[image]

This is the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<list>

using namespace std; 

void openInputFile(ifstream& inFile);

template<class T>
class Stack {
    list <T> data;

public:
    Stack() : data() {}
    void push(T newItem) { data.push_front(newItem); }
    T pop() { T topVal = top(); data.pop_front(); 
    return topVal; }
    T top() const { return *data.begin(); }
    bool isEmpty() const { return data.size() == 0; }
    int size() const { return data.size(); }
    void clear() { data.clear(); }
};

class brackets {

    brackets() : bracket() {}

    char bracket; 

};


int main()
{
    Stack<char> dataChecker; 
    ifstream inFile; 
    string charChecker; 
    char currChar; 
    int size;
    bool goodToGo = true; 

    cout << "First enter the name of the data file, 
    then press enter. " << endl;
    openInputFile(inFile);

    while (getline(inFile, charChecker)) {

        size = charChecker.size(); 

        if (charChecker.find("begin") || 
        charChecker.find("Begin") || 
        charChecker.find("BEGIN")) {

            dataChecker.push('b'); 
        }

        if (charChecker.find("end") || 
            charChecker.find("End") || 
            charChecker.find("END")) {

            currChar = dataChecker.pop();

            if (currChar != 'b') {
                goodToGo = false; 
                break; 
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i+= 1) {

            if ((charChecker[i] == '{') || 
               (charChecker[i] == '}') || 
               (charChecker[i] == '[') || 
               (charChecker[i] == ']') ||
               (charChecker[i] == '(') || 
               (charChecker[i] == ')')) {

                  switch (charChecker[i]) {

                    case '{' :
                        dataChecker.push('{');

                    case '[': 
                        dataChecker.push('[');

                    case '(':
                        dataChecker.push('(');

                    case '}':

                        currChar = dataChecker.pop();

                        if (currChar != '{') {
                            goodToGo = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    case ']':

                        currChar = dataChecker.pop();

                        if (currChar != '[') {
                            goodToGo = false;
                            break;
                        }

                    case ')':

                        currChar = dataChecker.pop();

                        if (currChar != '(') {
                            goodToGo = false;
                            break;
                        }



                }

            }




        }

    }

    if (goodToGo == false) {
        cout << "There is an error in the data." << 
         endl; 
    }

    else {
        cout << "The data looks good!" << endl;
    }




    return 0; 
}

void openInputFile(ifstream& inFile) {

    cout << "Please enter a filename: ";
    string filename;
    cin >> filename;
    inFile.open(filename);
    while (!inFile) {
        cout << "Bad file name";
        cout << "Please enter a filename: ";
        cin >> filename;
        inFile.clear();
        inFile.open(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't mean line 149 of your code, it means line 149 of the `<list>` header file

Comment: Anyway there is a special iterator value called the end of list iterator. It indicates a position past the end of the list. But there is no data at this position, so you aren't supposed to dereference the end of list iterator. But somewhere that's exactly what your program is doing.

Comment: It means pretty much what it says. You can't deference the iterator returned by `end`. It might be happening at `T top() const { return *data.begin(); }` or `T pop() { T topVal = top(); data.pop_front(); return topVal; }` if the list is empty.

Comment: Debug the program (per the instructions in the box) and the debugger will make it easy to go to the line of your code that triggers this as well as to see all the values of the variables you have at that point so you can figure out what is fishy and investigate how the program ended up like that.

Comment: Yes, basically you are trying to access the top value on the stack when the stack is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into line 149 of file `<list>` (the dialog message gives you the full path, also right-click and open on `#include <list>` in the editor helps):

```
    _NODISCARD reference operator*() const {
#if _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2
        const auto _Mycont = static_cast<const _Mylist*>(this->_Getcont());
        _STL_ASSERT(_Mycont, "cannot dereference value-initialized list iterator");
        _STL_VERIFY(this->_Ptr != _Mycont->_Myhead, "cannot dereference end list iterator");
#endif // _ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL == 2

        return this->_Ptr->_Myval;
    }
```

So this is simple. You have a list iterator (for example `iter`) and call `operator*` on it (-> `*iter`). That is not allowed and the assertion is telling you that. When you run the program in a debugger and look at the call stack you can directly navigate to the code where you call `*iter`.

Maybe you are calling `top` or `pop` on an empty Stack?